# find all natural $n$ for which $n^3-6n^2+10n-5$ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory

I want to find all natural $n>0$ for which $n^3-6n^2+10n-5$ is a perfect square.

---

Let $n^3-6n^2+10n-5=m^2$, then

$$n^3-6n^2+10n-5=(n-1)(n^2-5n+5)=m^2.$$

Clearly $(n,m)=(1,0)$ is an answer. Also, I found that $(n^2-5n+5)$ is always odd number.

Comment: Hint - can you find the highest common factor of $n-1$ and $n^2-5n+5$ and use this to reduce the options you are considering?

Comment: @MarkBennet not sure how to do it

Comment: You may be interested to know that if you subsititute $\,n+2\,$ for $\,n\,$ in your cubic you get $\,n^3-2n-1=(n^2-n-1)(n+1).\,$ Compare with the [elliptic curve with LMFDB label 80.a3](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/80/a/3) with only one integral point.

Comment: As in one of the answers below you use simple polynomial division. You know that the hcf will be an integer because you are dividing by a linear polynomial. In fact it comes out to $1$ and (as per answer below) both factors have to be square. If you are going to address questions like this one you will need something of a toolkit - so learning these basics will be essential for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that the two factors are coprime because
$$(n^2-5n+5)-(n-4)\cdot(n-1)=1.$$
As their product is a perfect square, both factors are perfect squares, meaning that
$$n-1=a^2\qquad\text{ and }\qquad n^2-5n+5=b^2,$$
for some integers $a$ and $b$. Then $n=a^2+1$ and so
$$b^2=n^2-5n+5=(a^2+1)^2-5(a^2+1)+5=a^4-3a^2+1.$$
So the quartic in $a$ on the right is a perfect square. Now it suffices to note that if $a^2>1$ then
$$(a^2-1)^2>a^4-3a^2+1>(a^2-2)^2,$$
so this quartic in $a$ can only be a perfect square if $a\in\{-1,0,1\}$. This corresponds to $n\in\{1,2\}$, and a quick check shows that only $n=1$ yields a solution, with $m=0$.